# Expand Laravel stack traces

Tags: php, debugging, laravel, laravel-4, xdebug

I am getting stack traces in my log that look like this:

```
[2015-01-28 00:33:12] local.ERROR: exception 'ErrorException' with message 'preg_replace(): Parameter mismatch, pattern is a string while replacement is an array' in /vagrant/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/helpers.php:900
Stack trace:
#0 [internal function]: Illuminate\Exception\Handler->handleError(2, 'preg_replace():...', '/vagrant/vendor...', 900, Array)
#1 /vagrant/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/helpers.php(900): preg_replace('/\\?/', Array, 'update `company...', 1)
#2 /vagrant/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/QueryException.php(55): str_replace_array('\\?', Array, 'update `company...')
#3 /vagrant/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/QueryException.php(37): Illuminate\Database\QueryException->formatMessage('update `company...', Array, Object(ErrorException))
#4 /vagrant/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php(627): Illuminate\Database\QueryException->__construct('update `company...', Array, Object(ErrorException))
#5 /vagrant/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php(581): Illuminate\Database\Connection->runQueryCallback('update `company...', Array, Object(Closure))
#6 /vagrant/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php(394): Illuminate\Database\Connection->run('update `company...', Array, Object(Closure))
#7 /vagrant/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php(339): Illuminate\Database\Connection->affectingStatement('update `company...', Array)
#8 /vagrant/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.php(1911): Illuminate\Database\Connection->update('update `company...', Array)
#9 /vagrant/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Builder.php(316): Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder->update(Array)
#10 /vagrant/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php(1514): Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder->update(Array)
#11 /vagrant/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php(1447): Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model->performUpdate(Object(Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder), Array)
#12 /vagrant/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Relations/HasOneOrMany.php(169): Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model->save()

etc...
```

What I would instead like is:

a) a setting or something that expands each line in the trace to its full/original message (how can I see that truncated stuff?):

```
#1 ... preg_replace('/\\?/', Array, 'update `company...', 1)
```

b) or otherwise disable Laravel's stack traces and just display plain-old-php stack traces. I have these xdebug settings turned on but I can't see the variables and dumps.

http://xdebug.org/docs/stack_trace

These are my xdebug settings:

```
[XDEBUG]
xdebug.remote_connect_back=1
xdebug.default_enable=1
xdebug.remote_autostart=0
xdebug.remote_enable=1
xdebug.remote_port=9000
xdebug.remote_handler=dbgp
xdebug.var_display_max_depth=5
xdebug.var_display_max_children=256
xdebug.var_display_max_data=1024

xdebug.collect_vars=1
xdebug.collect_params=4
xdebug.dump_globals=1
xdebug.show_local_vars=1

xdebug.show_mem_delta=1
```

I am doing a lot of AJAX work so the "whoops" page is of no help to me. I'd like everything to be logged for me to `tail -f` preferably.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried looking to see if there is a "Whoops" page sent back in the network tab in the dev console? Usually I just look at that on any ajax calls.